# Why should I not allow users to add their own HTML pages in my portal?

Tags: html

By default, SharePoint does now allow users to open HTML files in the browser. The unsafe file handler is added causing IE to download the file instead of opening it. You can alter this behaviour by registering HTML as a safe filetype, but what's the risk taken when doing so? I'd like to know what valid reasons there are to not allow users to open HTML files in the browser. This is based on a SharePoint farm used for intranet purposes, so it's not publically available and at this time there are also no external users on it.

Comment: This question reminds me of another recent one that solicited speculations about design decisions made by Microsoft when designing SharePoint and this is why I'm flagging it as not constructive

Comment: I agree with @MdMazzotti, no one here (probably) has any insight in Microsofts reasoning behind different design decisions. I'm therefor closing this as "Primarily opinion-based". By rephrasing your question, I think you possibly ask it on StackExchange.com under the header "Why should I not allow users to add their own HTML pages in my portal" or similar, lifting the question away from Microsofts specific decision, to a more generic question about dangers with HTML rendering.